# Loading a file From Wasm?

Tags: javascript, rust, webassembly

I am using rust and webassembly. I am getting this error message `operation not supported on wasm yet`. So either one of two things is happening, and I was curious if anyone knew the answer. So either my filepath is not correct and this is the least helpful error message, or wasm doesn't support loading files.

```
#[wasm_bindgen]
#[macro_use]
pub fn file() -> () {
    let mut data: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
    ///I would load the png with the same path in my javascript.
    let opened = File::open("./png/A_SingleCell.png");
    let unwraped = match opened {
        Ok(a) => log(&format!("opened {}", "worked")),
        Err(e) => log(&format!("{}", e)),
    };
    // .read_to_end(&mut data)
    // .unwrap();
    return ();
}

#[wasm_bindgen]
extern "C" {
    #[wasm_bindgen(js_namespace = console)]
    fn log(msg: &str);
}
```

and the javascript call is merely just `file()`.

Is there a different directory path I need to use to get the png or can you truly not load a file?

**Edit**
Adding my index.js to show that webpack has already loaded the png.

```
import { memory } from "break-game/break_game_bg";
import A from './png/A_SingleCell.png';
import { alloc, fill, decode, file } from "break-game";


file();
```

Comment: The browser cannot load files directly.  You need to use AJAX.

Comment: The file has already been packed and shipped with webpack

Comment: @christopherclark If Webpack is bundling it, then you're not loading a file at all, you're either loading a string or an array buffer that happens to originally come from a file.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Loading a file from the filesystem doesn't work with the Rust standard library and the `wasm32-unknown-unknown` target. This error is, consequently, an expected runtime error for using `File::open`.

The Rust standard library currently provides a uniform API surface area for all targets, regardless of whether the target actually supports the functionality or not. It turns out that almost all platforms implement basically all of the stable surface area of the standard library, but the `wasm32-unknown-unknown` target in specific is a bit of an odd-one-out. On this wasm target the standard library notably has no way to implement functions in modules like `std::net` or `std::fs`, so the functions unconditionally return an error. What you're seeing here is that `File::open` unconditionally returns an error on the `wasm32-unknown-unknown` target.

Speaking specifically about the `wasm32-unknown-unknown` target, this target is used to represent the "base layer of compatibility for Rust and wasm". On this target the standard library can only assume the WebAssembly instruction set, nothing else. Because WebAssembly provides no means of doing I/O or loading files, it means that these stubs are left to return errors in the standard library.

Note that an alternative way for us to provide the standard library on the `wasm32-unknown-unknown` target is to simply not provide these functions at all, causing a compile time error when they're attempted to be used. We chose to not take this route, for better or worse, to remain consistent across targets in Rust. It's hoped that something like the [proposed portability lint](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/41619) can change the calculus of this story, but Rust isn't quite there yet!

---

In the meantime, though, you probably still want to get this done! The `wasm-bindgen` project has a few guides about the `wasm32-unknown-unknown` target which may help you make some progress here:

- [Which crates will work off the shelf with WebAssembly?](https://rustwasm.github.io/book/reference/which-crates-work-with-wasm.html#which-crates-will-work-off-the-shelf-with-webassembly)
- [How to add WebAssembly support to a general purpose crate](https://rustwasm.github.io/book/reference/add-wasm-support-to-crate.html)

Notably the web platform doesn't currently provide the ability to load files from the filesystem, so there's no great way to implement `File::open` as an API in Rust for the `wasm32-unknown-unknown` target, even if JS is used. If you're using Node.js, though, I'd recommend reading about [JS interop](https://rustwasm.github.io/book/reference/js-ffi.html) as well as checking out the [`wasm-bindgen` guide](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/) for importing Node.js functions to implement this.

Comment: Thank you. I am curious though, because that file is "somewhere" on the client. It should be retrievable, maybe not using the standard library, but there should be some way to retrieve it no? or is wasm even sandboxed from the client?

Comment: Wasm in general for the web is just as sandboxed as a normal web page, so you'd access the file the same way in wasm that you would through a normal web page.

Comment: So i could theoretically make an ajax call to localhost/png/location.png and this would work! Thanks.

Comment: Would it also be possible to use the `include_bytes!()` macro, to embed a ressource like an Image into the .wasm binary?